# How to post data including a line break with libcurl (for Influxdb)?

Tags: c++, string, libcurl, line-breaks, influxdb

I am posting datapoints to InfluxDB using `libcurl` in C++. Single data points are working, but for multiple points, I am struggling on the necessary linebreak (\n), as defined in the [InfluxDB HTTP API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api/#write-http-endpoint):

> Write several points to the database with one request by separating each point by a new line.
>
> Write points from a file with the @ flag. The file should contain a batch of points in the Line Protocol format. Individual points must be on their own line and separated by newline characters (\n). Files containing carriage returns will cause parser errors.

I guess it might be an issue with the char formatting, but I can't figure out why? The following code just writes the 5 in distance but should write both distances.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include <string>
#include <curl\curl.h>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int dataPoints[] = { 3, 5 };
    std::string fieldIdentifier = "distance";

    std::stringstream ss;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        ss << "aufbau1,ort=halle ";
        ss << fieldIdentifier;
        ss << "=" << dataPoints[i];
        ss << std::endl; //I guess this is the problem, it adds \n
    }

    ss << "aufbau1,ort=halle ";
    ss << fieldIdentifier;
    ss << "=" << dataPoints[1];

    std::string data = ss.str();
    const char *dataChar = data.c_str();
    
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myIP:8086/write?db=testdb&u=myUser&p=myPwd");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, dataChar);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Set your stringstream to [binary mode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) with `stringstream ss(std::ios_base_out|std::ios_base::binary);` This will prevent the translation from `\n` to `\r\n`

Comment: @Botje I have tried the binary mode as you suggested. I guess you mean `std::ios_base::out` instead of `std::ios_base_out`? Unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: Try dumping the contents of `data` to a file (definitely don't forget `binary` mode there) and inspect it with a hex dumper. If that looks okay, try posting it with `curl --data-binary @file` as the manual suggests. Maybe there is something *else* wrong with your request.

Comment: The file looks good, with just `LF` at the end of the first line. But unfortunately `curl --data-binary @file` only adds the second data point, again.

Comment: Okay I actually missed something critical. When posting multiple data points to InfluxDB, a timestamp is mandatory. By adding it, everything worked fine, using the recommendations of @Botje to set the stringstream to `stringstream ss(std::ios_base_out|std::ios_base::binary);` Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

in python having a `<br>` html tag inside the tag/field value seems to act like a linebreak, while viewing this data in grafana.

regarding `\n` influxdb says

> Note: Line protocol does not support the newline character \n in tag values or field values.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/